# Create hidden file template in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

What is the best approach to creating a PhpStorm file template for a hidden file that pre-populates the file name (`.htaccess`) and does not include an extension?

The workflow currently is as follows:

1. Create file from template
2. Type in `.editorconfig` filename and hit 'ok'. Generated filename is `.editorconfig.`.
3. Rename `.editorconfig.` to `.editorconfig`.

Is it possible to optimize this workflow to:

1. Create file from template
2. 'editorconfig' filename prepopulated; simply hit 'ok'

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot create File Template using File & Code Templates functionality for extensionless files (e.g. `.editorconfig` or `.haccess`) using standard GUI as it requires file extension part.

Few options:

**1.** Write custom plugin that would offer such functionality -- that's what **.ignore plugin** does.

**2.** Create File Template using `.editorconfig` extension (IDE will ask what File Type to use to associate `*.editorfocnfig` files with; I would choose "Ini").

Then create new file `File | New | Your New FileTemplate` and give it some name (e.g. `a`) -- in the end you will have `a.editorconfig` file.

Now just rename it to `.editorconfig` only.

You seem to be doing already that (slightly different version of it).

**3.** Do not use any File Templates. Just create brand new empty file (`File | New | File`) -- here you have to specify full file name including extension .. so `.editorconfig` can be entered here.

Once done -- just use **Live Template** functionality and quickly paste needed content.

You just need to create such Live Template in advance and give it some easy to use and remember abbreviation (if you wish to enter such text by typing `abbreviation[TAB]` (e.g. `ec[TAB]` where `[TAB]` is the expand key).

- Live Templates official manual/how-to: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm
- Official Help pages: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/live-templates.html?search=live%20template